# Java override confusion

Tags: java

I am new to java, right now I got one question about method override:

```
public class maintest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Zi();
    }
}

public class Fu {

    public Fu() {
        show();
    }
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("This is from Fu show");
    }
}

public class Zi extends Fu {
    public Zi() {
        show();
        super.show();
    }

    public void show() {
        System.out.println("This is from zi show");
    }
}
```

When I run this program, the output is :

```
This is from zi show
This is from zi show
This is from Fu show
```

Could anyone give me some simple-understood explanation about why the first output line is

```
This is from zi show
```

rather than

```
This is from Fu show
```

By another mean, why the show method in super class is hidden?

Comment: You overrode the method in `Zi`, so `Zi` objects that call `show()` will always call the `Zi` version.

Comment: @dlev I do not quite understand, when super() is called, why it runs in Zi's context? Could you show it in th perspective of Memory location? (Like JVM structure)

Comment: if you did not have a show in your Fu constructor, you should see what you expect.

Comment: This question has been asked a dozen times or more. You should try searching SO for this before posting a new question.

Comment: @leigero thanks for tip. I just have no idea which keyword I should search because I am pretty new to java.

Answer (score 4):

In your constructor you do this,

```
public Zi() {
  super(); // <-- you didn't have this, so the compiler added it.
           // your Fu class then calls Zi's show.
           // Why? Because Zi has a method named show that override Fu's
           // show method. So the Fu constructor (when it calls show()) gets the 
           // show implementation in Zi.
  show(); // <-- first explicit show call (but the second "This is from zi show")
  super.show(); // <-- then call the Fu.show()
}
```

Comment: Why the keyword "this" in super() refer to Zi?

Comment: Not the key word "this"... but there is an implicit call to the super() constructor - I added it (the super()).

Comment: @Kuan It's just how Java works.  In any constructor, Java will _implicitly_ make a call to the superclass constructor at the very beginning.  The answerer showed you how it looks explicitly, so you can see that why your output had three lines, and not the two you probably expected.

Comment: @Kuan "this" refers to the object of class Zi.

Comment: @Adtya thanks for explanation, but what if I want to use Fu's show in super()? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

When `new Zi()` is invoked,

It invokes its constructor

```
    Zi() {
        a. super(); //the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-  argument constructor of the superclass
        b. show();
        c.super.show();  
    }
```

**a.** when `super()` class constructor is called. it finds `show()` method.. (Since object reference is from Zi class, so Zi's `show()` returns **"This is from zi show"**)

```
  public Fu() {
           System.out.println(this.getClass().getName()); //add this.. it will return           **"Zi"**
           show(); // So this will return Zi's show(), due to refrence of Zi's object, when called by the sub class constructor.
   }
```

**b.** `show()` - will return **"This is from zi show"**

**c.** `super.show()` - will return super's `show()`

Comment: thanks for explanation, but what if I want to use Fu's show in super()? How can I do that?

Comment: Since the object reference is Zi's object in super(), so it will invoke zi's show() method always, to show Fu's show() method, you have to explicitly define the type reference of the object to Fu's type. so that it will invoke..

Comment: @sakura, Yes, I need, and sorry for not formating.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Super class `Fu` constructor invoke the method `show` which you have already overrided in subclass, so overrided method has been called.

Comment: thanks for explanation, but what if I want to use Fu's show in super()? How can I do that?

Comment: Simply you can not.But in sub class method if invoke `super.show()` then super method will be called

Comment: So,  does it mean: a good pattern is never overide a method which is in superclass' constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider each line of the output.

The first line is coming from the first call to `show()` in the constructor of `Fu`, which is implicitly called **before** the call to the constructor of `Zi`.

The second line is from `show()` inside the constructor of `Zi`.

The third line comes from `super.show()` which explicitly calls the `show()` method on the parent class `Fu`.

Comment: Why the first show() is in the context of Zi rather than Fu?If the first show in Fu's show, why that this refer to Zi?

Comment: When a method is overriden in a subclass and we are constructing an instance of the subclass, all calls to the method will go to the subclass's method, unless explicitly overriden (such as with `super`) in the case above. It is not about the "context", it is about the type of the object being constructed. Here we are constructing an object of type `Zi`, so even though `Fu`'s constructor calls `show()`, it is still calling `Zi`'s `show`.

Comment: thanks for explanation, but what if I want to use Fu's show in super()? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `show` in Fu constructor, the show method of real Object that is Zi now be invoked.

basically in memory there is only one object that is either Fu and Zi. the show method of this object is deepest (in inheritance tree) overriden version of it that in this case is Zi's show.

Comment: Could you give me some detail about how the method show both in Fu and Zi stored in memeory?

Answer (score 0):

You have overridden the Fu.show by Zi.show. That means even when you call show() inside your parent class, the child class method get called.

In an real example,

Your father(Parent) has a company. you(Child) inherits that from him. You appoints a new Receptionist(override the parent's receptionist by child). Now all the calls comes to Father's company will be received by your Receptionist.

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I guess I may need to read more to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

You can check what was the flow of your program. Check output from `System.err.println()` method.

```
public class maintest {

    static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Zi();
    }
}

class Fu {

    public Fu() {
        System.err.println("Fu Constructor " + maintest.i++);
        show();
    }
    public void show() {
        System.err.println("Fu show " + maintest.i++);
        System.out.println("This is from Fu show");
    }
}

class Zi extends Fu {
    public Zi() {
        System.err.println("Zi Constructor " + maintest.i++);
        show();
        super.show();
    }

    public void show() {
        System.err.println("Zi show " + maintest.i++);
        System.out.println("This is from zi show");
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
This is from zi show
This is from zi show
This is from Fu show
Fu Constructor 0
Zi show 1
Zi Constructor 2
Zi show 3
Fu show 4
```

The sequence of output from `System.out.println()` and `System.err.println()` may vary.

The above output tells that first the object of `Fu` class is made (as `Zi` class `extends` `Fu`) then `show()` method and `constructor` of `Zi` class is called then because of `super.show()` `show()` method of `Fu` class is called. Which is your output.